# Why is my SQL Server data deleted when application stopped?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq-to-sql

I have one table in SQL Server that contains `datetime` columns. I use LINQ to SQL.

While running the program all data is saved in a table and I get all the results properly.

But as soon as I close the run, there is no data in the table and the `getall` function returns null.

I can not find the problem.

The code to insert data into a table is:

```
public bool AddTime(WorkTime ToAdd)
{
    try
    {
        _context.WorkTimes.InsertOnSubmit(ToAdd);
        _context.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Don't return true or false depending on whether an exception is thrown and just swallow the exception.  How is calling code supposed to know what went wrong?

Comment: Either you're reading the table wrong, you have an open transaction that rolls bak, or you have a DELETE somewhere. Data does not disappear

Comment: **Show us** your connection string! Most likely, you have a `AttachDbFileName=....` and `User Instance=true` in there - those are kinda "throw away" approaches ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, you using a SQL Server Express Edition standalone file, that is getting re-deployed (copied to the output folder) every time you build.

Options:

- register a database inside the engine itself, rather than using a standalone file, or
- take care not to overwrite your database when you build

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how to register the DB in the engine?

Comment: @Avrahamshuk do you have SSMS (there is a free version)? If so, connect to `.\SQLEXPRESS` (typically), right click on "Databases", and select "Attach". Then change your connection string to use that data source